# How to get Current.Server.MapPath?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC.I want to save xml file inside the services class.
so wrote this one.

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath((Url.Content("~/client-authentication.xml")));
```

but there is error and it says

```
'System.Security.Policy.Url' does not contain a definition for 'Content'
```

How to solve it??
How can I give the path??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this code in your view(.cshtml) or controller(.cs)?

if cshtml, you can write "string path = Url.Content(...)" directly, no need Server.MapPath.

if controller, just Server.MapPath(...), no need Url.Content.

PS, you can also use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to retrive physical path of your site root.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong `Url` class. You want the [System.MVC.Web.UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) instance called [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.url%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) which is a property provided on MVC controllers.